# Markers in Openlayer LineString

Tags: openlayers-3

Is there anyway to divide the openlayer line into equal segments? I want to generate markers at defined interval in the line.

Comment: I believe openlayers has no built-in functionality for this, but it can be easily done with a bit of your own code. If this answer is not enough, I can prepare a fiddle when I get to my computer.

Comment: yes please. If you can, please let me know, how can it be done? Thanks.

Comment: Also, the line is not straight. It could have multiple vertices.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script that splits a linestring into *n* equally long segments and generates a point geometry at each split point: https://gist.github.com/Kenny806/37c767f46bcb2687e0ae

I understand you wanted to split a line into segments by defining the length of a segment, rather than number of segments, but you can get the number of segments easily like this:

```
var n = geometry.getLength() / desiredSegmentLength;
```

Of course, you should make sure that n is a positive integer.

Hope this helps

Comment: There's an example of a modified version of that script being used for styling here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/306976/add-image-along-the-linestring/306979